# Hatching of region between two defined functions in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having a bit of difficulty. I would like to shade in the region where the black data points lie in the following figure (ignore the histograms):

[image]

The two functions are as follows:

Solid black curve:

```
def log_OIII_Hb_OII(log_OII_Hb, eps=0):
    return eps + ((0.11)/(log_OII_Hb - eps -0.92)) + 0.85
```

Linear dotted line:

```
def LINERlog_OIII_Hb_OII(log_OII_Hb, eps=0):
    return 0.95*(log_OII_Hb)-0.4
```

I am familiar with `axScatter.fill_between`, but I am not sure the best way to shade in the aforementioned region. Suggestions are very much welcome. I have also defined some `np.linspaces` for both functions, but I'm sure the shade can be done with:

```
np.linspace(-0.5, 2.0).
```

Comment: I suspect you are going to want to use clipping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fill_between` for that. Here's it is applied to hatch a region between `sin(a)` and `cos(a)`:

[image]

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from numpy import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

a = linspace(0, 6.28, 100)

x = sin(a)
y = cos(a)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(a, x, "k-", lw=3)
ax.plot(a, y, "k-", lw=3)

ax.fill_between(a, x, y, hatch = '///')

fig.savefig("mwe.png")
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response Adobe, so how would I apply this to my functions? I can generate x values with np.linspace = x so I can do something like a, f(x), f(y). Would you know specifically how to hatch my region in? I've tried a lot of various things!